# Selenium unable to find Button

Tags: python, html, selenium, button

I am trying to click on the "Next Page"-Button on the Web of Science Search-Site to iterate through all pages.
Here is a screenshot of the HTML of the page (highlighted is the button)
[image: HTML]

This is my code to find the button:

`driver.find_element_by_class_name('mat-focus-indicator mat-icon-button mat-button-base').click()`

But I receive this error:
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".mat-focus-indicator mat-icon-button mat-button-base"}

I have tried so many ways of identifying the button (find_by_id, find_by_name, find_by_link_text) but nothing works.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: Please [edit] you question to include the HTML as code, rather than a screenshot. You can copy the HTML directly from the HTML inspector in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try with Query Selector like:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[data-ta="next-page-button"]')
```

You can always try selectors on elemnts panel (like on screenshort) and type your selector in field "Find by string, css, or xpath"

Answer (score 0):

Class name do not have support for **spaces**, **remove spaces** and put `.` to make it **css selector :**

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.mat-focus-indicator.mat-icon-button.mat-button-base').click()
```

also try to put some wait before this to make it more consistent.